# Set image position to page center

Tags: wpf, printdialog

I'm trying to print an image in the center of the page but I can't come up with any idea.

```
System.Windows.Point printLocation = new System.Windows.Point(50,50);
printLocation.X = pageWidth - 50 / 2; 50 is the margin
imageViewer = ImagePrintAdapter.CreateImageFromBitmapImage(img,printLocation);
printerDialog.PrintVisual(imageViewer, "Identification");
```

This is the `CreateImageFromBitmapImage`method

```
public static System.Windows.Controls.Image CreateImageFromBitmapImage(BitmapImage imgSource, System.Windows.Point imgLocation)
 {
   System.Windows.Controls.Image imageViewer = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
   imageViewer.BeginInit();
   imageViewer.Source = imgSource;

   imageViewer.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
   imageViewer.Arrange(new System.Windows.Rect(imgLocation, imageViewer.DesiredSize));

   imageViewer.EndInit();
   imageViewer.UpdateLayout();

   return imageViewer;
}
```

If I set the printLocation.X to be the half of the pageWidth, shouldn't it start at the center ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply draw the image into a DrawingVisual and print it. The following simplified example assumes that the bitmap size is smaller than the printable area size:

```
ImageSource image = ...

var rect = new Rect(
    (printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth - image.Width) / 2,
    (printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight - image.Height) / 2,
    image.Width, image.Height);

var visual = new DrawingVisual();
using (var dc = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    dc.DrawImage(bitmap, rect);
}

printDialog.PrintVisual(visual, "");
```

Note that you may as well use any other size for the Rectangle, i.e. scale the printed image accordingly.